# Modular structure for Express 4 backend in a MEAN app

Tags: node.js, express, dry, mean-stack

I'm newbie developing MEAN apps, i'm coming from a Laravel structure to develop web applications, what i don't like about Laravel is that is not so modular, everything is separated, especially Models, Views, and Controllers, to navigate through the folders you have to scroll a lot of times when building large apps...

My question is all about Express under the MEAN stack, what i'm looking for is a structure where i create modules for every entity of an app, for example:

I have three modules: **users**, **questions**, and **answers**; each module will contain the routes, the model, and the controller for that specific module, for example:

```
├── node_modules
├── src
│   ├── client
│   │   └── ... //Frontend things managed by angular (like views, etc...)
│   └── server
│       ├── modules //By module i mean an entity
|       |   ├── users
|       |   |   ├── users.model.js
|       |   |   ├── users.controller.js
|       |   |   ├── users.routes.js
|       |   |   └── index.js
|       |   ├── questions
|       |   └── answers
|       ├── config
|       └── etc... //Suggestions please...
|
├── package.json
└── server.js
```

How could i set up that structure?, so far i've found [this tutorial](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/modular-node-js-express/) about modularizing an Express app, but i would like to extend it, so that i keep it DRY, and make use of the [LIFT principle](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y140) described by John Papa in his Angular Style Guide but under the backend.

Why am i asking this? Simple, i don't like to scroll through large folders to get open a file and then scroll again to open another file that are related, i want to work with a structure easy to maintain, easy to understand, etc...

If possible could someone explain an example of how to setup an application using this structure and upload it to github?

Comment: I would suggest against having multiple node_modules folders. Doing so would mean you actually have nested applications, and each node_modules folder would need it's own package.json.

Comment: I'm using MySQL as db instead of MongoDB, so i'm using sequelize as ORM

Comment: Your structure looks fine to me, other than the nested node_modules folder.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, what i don't know is how to set it up to work with it, there's where i'm struggling

Comment: To work with what? the nested node-modules folder? i don't either, and i don't wish to explore it. seems like a really bad practice to me. If i went that route, i would instead develop each of those as separate modules entirely that you install into the root node_modules folder.

Comment: Well, the nested node_modules isn't something i really want to do, in fact, i find it unnecessary, but it would be interesting to do it, what i really want is to keep each model, controller and routes separated by module

Comment: well, that's easy. Give each module folder an index.js, and have that index.js pull that module together, just as you have it structured. You'll have to give more details on what exactly you're stuck on, at this point we can't really explain it to you without building it for you, top to bottom.

Comment: @KevinB To make this structure work, i don't know how will i implement it... i'm a bit new to Express and Node, what i'm asking for is how will i have to configure the models, the routes, and the controllers to make them work under this structure

Comment: that's way too broad, sorry. There are hundreds of different ways to accomplish that.

Comment: @KevinB Could you make an example app using this structure please?, i don't really know how to do it, in fact i don't know too much about setting up a Node app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89426/discussion-between-jonathan-s-and-kevin-b).

Comment: why don't you try checking out [meanjs](https://github.com/meanjs/mean) repository

Answer (score 0):

Place one node_modules at the top level.

Give each module a package.json

Now write a script in your bootstrap that finds all unique node_modules required from the package.json.

There, node_modules solved. Make sure it identifies the variances of versions too.

Build a universal run script file that reads a universal configuration file that points to all of the other modules.

Angular 2..4..5 whatever is a great modularized file structure to model after.

Comment: Please, try to be more descriptive in your answer since it contains a lot of references not properly described.